# Liferay theme upgrade from 5.2 to 6.1

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I am upgrading Liferay from 5.2 to 6.1. I want to know similar to core liferay, for theme also we have to follow two steps up-gradation (i.e from 5.2 to 6.0 then 6.0 to 6.1) or we can directly go for 5.2 to 6.1 theme upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The theme doesn't require any sort of upgrade process so you'll only need to rewrite it once.
Basically you'll just need to make sure that the theme is using 6.1 API and AUI.

The most complicated of the two being migrating from jQuery to AUI (YUI).

Here is a "rosetta stone" to get you started: http://www.jsrosettastone.com/

Comment: Sorry forgot to note that AUI is a Liferay extension to Yahoo!'s YUI

Comment: Thanks @RP for your comments. Can you suggest me how I have to proceed for up-gradation as our Liferay 5.2 theme has lots of customization. So, is there any way to retain that customization or I have to write the 6.1 theme from scratch?

Comment: Please describe what your theme does. What does it change? At best you can just continue to use it without rewriting a line of code.

Comment: Say for example customization for colors and width etc then how we use the same customization in new theme. We have to paste one by one each customization or is there any other way for this?

Comment: There's also a Rosetta Stone including AUI: http://deploy.alloyui.com/docs/ - it's well hidden, can't remember how I found it

Comment: If it is some basic CSS changes, then I would go ahead and try to deploy the theme into the new version. There will be some things that are off or css classes that are missing. But you can just patch up the rough spots.

Comment: Thanks Olaf and Ryan:)                                                               I will try to deploy the new theme and follow the CSS customization. I will update my progress soon.

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade is not like the core liferay.

Steps (more of a check-list) to look for when upgrading themes:

1) You have to change the liferay-look-and-feel.xml's <version>6.1+</version>.

2) You would need to manually include jQuery, as now it is not part of Liferay ([Alloy UI](http://alloy.liferay.com/) is now a part). You can include them through the template files (*.vm).

3) There are a lot of customizations in the template files (portal_normal.vm, portlet.vm, navigation.vm etc) from 5.2 to 6.1, so if you have done customizations to these then you would have to again customize them.

4) Also a lot of CSS changes have happened since 5.2, infact 6.1 UI is almost completely different from 5.2. So you will have to again style liferay html elements as it now uses alloy UI JSP tags to render them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Prakash I will check the above mentioned suggestion and try to implement it. In case of further problem I will post here. Also, can you provide me some good links for theme upgrade tutorial as Liferay official documentation for theme upgrade is not explained well.

Comment: The upgrade has no standard steps apart from what I mentioned and what is given in the Liferay Wiki here: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Upgrade+5.2.x+Themes+to+6.0.x, and most of the things depend on your customizations

Comment: Sure, I will follow your instruction and in case of problem I will post here. Thanks